# How do I use Touch Up Inside for several buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

I am trying to make a label's text change to different text based on the buttons pressed. For example, if `btn_1` is pressed `label_1` will show some text, and when `btn_2` is pressed, it'll show something else.

So what I have right now is

```
@IBOutlet weak var label_1 : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btn_1 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn_2 : UIButton!
@IBAction func onTapChangeText(_ sender:Any) {
    label_1.text = "Hello"
}
```

The problem now is that anytime I tap on any button it changes the text
to "Hello". But I only want to it change when `btn_1` is pressed, not also `btn_2`.

I tried changing it to:

```
@IBAction func onTapChangeText(_ sender:btn_1) {
    label_1.text = "Hello"
}
```

However, it just calls an error. I also tried

```
@IBAction func onTapChangeText(_ sender:Any) {
    if sender == btn_1 {
        label_1.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work. It returns an error instead (No surprise however)

I'm new to Xcode, but not to general coding. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

By the way: all the buttons are linked, the label is linked, and the buttons are link to call a onTapChangeText() from the ViewController on Touch Up Inside.

Answer (score 2):

You could use separate action methods for each button or you can fix the error and have a single method handle all the buttons. You didn’t show the error, but I assume it is:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'UIButton'

This occurs because the default type for `sender` when an action is created in Interface Builder is `Any`. Since you know they are buttons you can change the type and should then be able to determine which button was tapped:

```
@IBAction func onTapChangeText(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender == btn_1 {
        label_1.text = "Hello"
    } else if sender == btn_2 {
        label_1.text = "Goodbye”
    }
}
```

It is also possible to change the type from `Any` to the exact type when creating the action by changing the properties in Interface Builder (away from Mac so can’t show a screenshot).

Comment: I would use `sender === btn_X` since you want to compare instances, not equality.